# I'm trying to get the maximum number by passing the string

Tags: python

```
def find_color(input):
   input = input.replace("rgb"," ")
   return (max(input.split(' ')))
print(find_color("rgb(125, 50, 175)"))
```

The below code gives 50 as the maximum number. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please refer to this guide on How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of mistakes in your code :

- You need to remove the enclosing parentheses from the string first.
- You need to split on `', '` and then convert to int also.

Modified code :

```
def find_color(input):
   input = input.replace("rgb","")[1:-1] # input = "125, 50, 175"
   return (max(map(int, input.split(', '))))
```

Also, since input is already a tuple(string of a tuple), you can also do `return (max(eval(input)))`

Answer (score 1):

split will create a list of strings - therefore you compare in alphabetical order. In alphabetical order '50' > '175'.

You should convert the list to list of integers.

you can use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) for this task :

```
def find_color(input):
   input = input.replace("rgb(","").replace(")","").replace(' ' , '' )
   return max(map(int,input.split(',')))
print(find_color("rgb(125, 50, 175)"))
```